# How does this series converge?

Tags: real-analysis

If $0<b<1$, then prove that $nb^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Now, I think I did this correctly, but it seems a little too simple of a proof. I said that if $0<b<1$, then we can write $b=\frac{p}{q}$ where $|p|<|q|$. Then, $nb^n \implies n(\frac{p}{q})^n \implies n \cdot \frac{p^n}{q^n}$ and $\lim_{n=1}^\infty = \infty \cdot 0 = 0$. I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this because in the problem, I was told to use calculus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $\infty\cdot 0=0$? Infinity times zero is not well-defined notion!

Comment: If you believe $\infty\cdot 0=0$, then you should equally conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{b^n}=0$.  But the limit and its reciprocal can't both be zero!

Comment: OK, I thought there was something wrong with my argument. Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: Is it just beginning of a calculus course, or you know more advanced tool, e.g. series? (It seems to be a simmple corollary from one of theorems of theory of series).

Comment: This is actually from Analysis lol, I'm having trouble refreshing my mind on calculus matters.

Comment: So, if I use the ratio test to show that this series converges, how can I find the actual convergence point?

Comment: For a sum to converge, it is necessary that the terms tend to $0$. So if you can show that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}nb^n$ converges, then you have shown that $nb^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So we can say that if this converges to $0$, then for $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N \implies Nb^N < \epsilon$.

Comment: The title says series, but the question is about a sequence. Please clarify --- is there actually a series involved here, and if so, what series? and if not, please edit the title to reflect the question.

Comment: Are you still here, RXY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever $b$ is a rational or irrational, there must exist a rational $r=\frac pq$ such that $b<r<1$.

Now consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\frac{p^n}{q^n}$. Does it converge?

In fact, you can take $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac pq<1$$

So it converges, which implies that $n\frac{p^n}{q^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

SO $nb^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$